# RPC communication between C# and android application

Tags: c#, rpc, .net-4.5

I really need your help guys. I'm trying to make C# console application to communicate with android application (basically java). C# application is primary server but I need both sides communication (both sides remote functions calling with returns).

Can you advice me some tutorial, or sample project, anything :-(

or should I use JSON-RPC? or RPC-XML?.. I'm really lost.

**Edit**

I'm trying to call C# function from Android application and get back answer (for example `Object[]`) and same thing from Android to C#. Both are on same network.

Comment: [Deserialize JSON object sent from Android app to WCF webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165533/deserialize-json-object-sent-from-android-app-to-wcf-webservice)

Comment: Vote to Close; question is too broad and it all depends on what you are trying to do and your experience. However, since you mentioned JSON-RPC you might want to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/ and http://jayrock.berlios.de/ on the C# side.

Comment: Not voting to close. I **really** want to know the answer to this :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) on server side. From Androids perspective, it will be pure Java to Java RPC, at server side You will effectivly code at .NET.