# How to pass and consume a JSON parameter to/with RESTful WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, wcf-rest

I am a beginner at RESTful services.

I need to create an interface where the client needs to pass up to 9 parameters.

I would prefer to pass the parameters as a JSON object.

For instance if my JSON is:

```
'{
    "age":100,
    "name":"foo",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "favoriteColor" : "blue",
    "petName" : "Godzilla",
    "IQ" : "QuiteLow"
}'
```

And if I need to execute a server side method below in the end:

```
public Person FindPerson(Peron lookUpPerson)
{
Person found = null;
// Implementation that finds the Person and sets 'found'
return found;
}
```

**Question(s):**
How should I make the call from the client-side with the above JSON string?
And how can I create a signature and implementation of the RESTful service method that

- accepts this JSON,
- parses and deserializes it into Person object and
- calls / returns the FindPerson method's return value back to client?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165533/deserialize-json-object-sent-from-android-app-to-wcf-webservice

Comment: Which language are you using to call the service? JavaScript, C#, something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to create a WCF operation to receive that JSON input, you'll need to define a data contract which maps to that input. There are a few tools which do that automatically, including one which I wrote a while back at http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/ (more details on how this tool was written at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/12/creating-asp-net-web-apis-on-azure-web-sites.aspx)). The tool generated this class, which you can use:

```
// Type created for JSON at <<root>>
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class Person
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int age;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string name;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string[] messages;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string favoriteColor;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string petName;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string IQ;
}
```

Next, you need to define an operation contract to receive that. Since the JSON needs to go in the body of the request, the most natural HTTP method to use is `POST`, so you can define the operation as below: the method being "POST" and the style being "Bare" (which means that your JSON maps directly to the parameter). Notice that you can even omit the `Method` and `BodyStyle` properties, since `"POST"` and `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` are their default values, respectively).

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public Person FindPerson(Peron lookUpPerson)
{
    Person found = null;
    // Implementation that finds the Person and sets 'found'
    return found;
}
```

Now, at the method you have the input mapped to `lookupPerson`. How you will implement the logic of your method is up to you.

*Update after comment*

One example of calling the service using JavaScript (via jQuery) can be found below.

```
var input = '{
    "age":100,
    "name":"foo",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "favoriteColor" : "blue",
    "petName" : "Godzilla",
    "IQ" : "QuiteLow"
}';
var endpointAddress = "http://your.server.com/app/service.svc";
var url = endpointAddress + "/FindPerson";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: input,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

Comment: Very useful answer carlosfigueira! (Can you also add the Javascript call so that it can cover all parts roughly) Thanks!

Comment: I have asked how to replace this jquery ajax call with a JavaScript builtin functions usage only :) (See my last question, if interested :) )

Comment: The sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb472488(v=vs.100).aspx shows one way of doing that, using the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` may work for you if `Bare` causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

1-Add the WebGet attribute

```
<OperationContract()> _
        <WebGet(UriTemplate:="YourFunc?inpt={inpt}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)> _
        Public Function YourFunch(inpt As String) As String
```

2-Use NewtonSoft to serialize/deserialize your json into your object (note the above just takes in String), NewtonSoft is much faster than the MS serializer.

use NewtonSoft for serialization http://json.codeplex.com/

3- your .svc file will contain Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory

4- your web.config will contain

```
     <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

...and...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: If you want to pass a JSON input to a WCF service, you shouldn't use `[WebGet]` - the input should be passed in the request body, so GET shouldn't be used for that. It should use `[WebInvoke]` instead.