# Pass Serialized object to WCF method, when object class has attribute [Serializable]

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

My problem is that I want to send post request with serialized object to WCF method
Here is my code.

```
[Serializable]
public class StandardCardModel
{
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string app_source { get; set; }
    public string card { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetLastTransactions")]
    LastTransactionsResult GetLastTransactions(StandardCardModel scm);
```

Now I want to call 'GetLastTransactions' with param :

```
{
 "lang": "en",
 "app_source": "TestSource",
 "card": "1111"
}
```

To be clear, I don't want to send JSON with param name as object. ex :

```
{"scm":{....}}
```

I am getting null in scm. Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: I found an answer to my question [here][1]. Thanks



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915765/how-to-pass-and-consume-a-json-parameter-to-with-restful-wcf-service

Answer (score 0):

remove `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`. With `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`the request must be wrapped.

Comment: No, It is not solution. Thanks

Comment: try from SOAP UI or Fiddler.Works for me