# Technology for cross-platform embedable .net Rest API

Tags: c#, linux, rest, asp.net-web-api, mono

We have a *.net server* application, originally developed for windows. Now, we move it to **linux** platform (using mono + postgre instead of ms sql) and we also want to implement **RESTful** API for it, which can use **AppDomain** resources such as **caches**, some internal objects and so on. And so, we need a framework to built such an API. It'll be very good if can also built some web-interface using **Razor** or something, but it's not main in this case.

So far I've tried **NancyFx** which looks really promising, but I've encountered some errors running it on mono, for example, when I run my test app on windows with **nancy** self-hosting, it works really good. But, when executed with **mono** (on windows also), it lacks performance and gives me a little strange responses.

For example, for a simple method like below:

```
Get["/IsActive"] = param =>
            {
                var json = Response.AsJson(true);
                return json;
            };
```

I get simply `true` in .net execution and

```
P/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2015 18:05:24 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100

4
true
0
```

and on mono I get this response really slow. I guess it's some `mono` issues with `HttpHandler` or something...

So, what platform now is best for building embedable REST service for my server .net application running on linux with Mono?

Comment: Try WCF..............

Comment: I hate WCF for it's configurations. At first we tried to port our existing SOAP Service to Mono that was a really pain. I don't think that's a real good choice till MS port WCF to Mono

Comment: **a)** All of my WCF codes (developed in .Net) run perfectly on mono. **b)** I hate those configurations too, Therefore I use *WebServiceHost* like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165533/deserialize-json-object-sent-from-android-app-to-wcf-webservice

Comment: Side note: Is this "tools and libraries recommendations" or "express your opinion on libraries" type of question?

Comment: @EZI AFAIK, WCF isn't officially supported by the mono project, do you use some mono side/dev branch ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, both'll be appreciated, because i can't find much info to start with. On windows, ofc, there is much info, but on linux...

Comment: @ShmilTheCat they have parial support, which lacks realy HUGE functionality, so some thing become a real pain, as i mentioned before